# How can i use export default function from store( Vue)?

Tags: vue.js, store

I have some extra code from another guy. and i don't know how can i use it

i tried use this function,like any other component from store in index.js
in index.js i registred modules:

```
export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {},
  getters: {},
  mutations: {},
  actions: {

  },
  modules: {
    person,
    applications,
  },
  strict: false
});

let fillTotal = function (s) {
return{...}};
export default function (fatJSON) {
  let obj = fillTotal(fatJSON);
  obj = Object.assign(demoObj, obj);

  axios.post(
    'http://someaddress',
    obj
  ).then(r => console.log(r));
  // console.log('obj', obj);
  // console.log('fatStore', fatStore);
}
```

My component:

```
template>
  <div>
    <div class="clear_save_button row">
        <button @click="onSave">Сохранить</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  import myFunction from '/src/store/index.js'
 methods: {
        executeMyFunction(FatJson){
          myFunction(FatJson);
        },
        onSave() {
          this.executeMyFunction(this.person);
            AXIOS.post(`/profile`, (this.person))
              .then(response => {...
```

I have post method in component like: AXIOS.post(`/profile`, (this.person))
how send this.person used this function from store?

Comment: If it's just a method then it should reside in the component's `methods` object.

Comment: @Terry
Do you mean just use this.fillTotal(something) in my method in component?

Comment: Something like `methods: { fillTotal() { ... } }`

Comment: @Terry  Error in v-on handler: "ReferenceError: fillTotal is not defined"

Comment: Show us a minimal, concrete, and verifiable example of your VueJS component. We aren't clairvoyants here.

Comment: @Terry, i updated question:)Sorry

Answer (score -1, accepted):

just import that function and call it inside a method like this :

**UPDATED :**

```js
// src/store/index.js

let fillTotal = function(s) {...}
export const myFunction = (fatJSON) => {
  let obj = fillTotal(fatJSON);
  obj = Object.assign(demoObj, obj);
  axios.post(
    'http://1ss.loc',
    obj
  ).then(r => console.log(r));
}


// in component.vue

import {myFunction} from '@/src/store/index.js';
export default {
  methods: {
    executeMyFunction() {
      myFunction();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: import myFunction from '@/function.js'; - in my case i should to write import myFunction from '@/index.js' ?
myFunction - is it just name for anon function in index.js?
"Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/src/store/index.js' in " -is it mean i have some mistake in way to index.js?

Comment: @Montego or show us where the function lives inside your store

Comment: @Montego maybe you have other exports ... i will update the answer so you import the exact function

Comment: i updated my question with more code info. Maybe it'll help

Comment: @Montego Great , my updated answer should work for you unless you have some file naming errors.